# SQL Server 2005 Insert with WHILE LOOP

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to get the result like this

[image]

Here is my code

```
declare @current int
declare @Temp Table(c1 int, c2 int, c3 int, c4 int, c5 int, c6 int, c7 int, c8 int, c9 int, c10 int)
select @current = 1
while @current <= 10
    begin
        --I want to insert here
        select @current = @current + 1
    end
select * from @Temp
```

How can I insert? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into @temp(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10)
    select 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10;
```

There is no reason to use a `while` loop.  In general, you should be thinking in a set-based way, rather than an iterative way, when using SQL.

Answer (score 1):

No need of `while` loop to do this

```
Insert into @temp(c1,c2,c3,.c10)
select @current-1,@current,@current+1,..@current+9
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid `WHILE` in this case using `INSERT ... SELECT with CROSS JOIN`:

```
declare @Temp Table(c1 int, c2 int, c3 int, c4 int, c5 int, c6 int, c7 int, c8 int, c9 int, c10 int)

insert into dbo.TargetTable (...columns...)
select t.*, n.Num
from @Temp t
cross join (
select 1 union all 
select 2 union all 
select 3 union all 
select 4 union all 
select 5 union all 
select 6 union all 
select 7 union all 
select 8 union all 
select 9 union all 
select 10 
) n(Num)
```

or (within **sqlcmd / SSMS**) using `GO` (this keyword isn't T-SQL keyword/statement):

```
insert into dbo.TargetTable (...columns...)
values (...)
go 10
```

`go 10` executes current SQL Server batch ten times.